# Apparent discrepency of statements in Hartshorne exercise III.9.3c

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In exercise III.9.3c, we are asked to prove that for the affine scheme $X=\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y,z,w]/(z^2,zw,w^2,xz-yw)$ over $Y=\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]$,

1. $X_{\text{red}}=Y$;
2. $X$ has no embedded points;
3. The natural morphism $f:X\to Y$ induced by the inclusion homomorphism is not flat.

I had a hard time in proving statement 2 and 3.

My approach is as follows: Find $P\in X$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ is not a free $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(P)}$-module. But I had a hard time in showing any of the statement, I also haven't try the case when $P$ is not a closed point.

From the ideal of definition, points in $X$ written in affine coordinates has the form $(a,b,0,0)$ for some $a,b\in k$.

At the point $(1,0,0,0)$ (similarly for $(0,1,0,0)$), using the relation $xz-yw=0$ and the invertibility of $x$, $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}=k[x,y,z]_{(x-1,y,z)}/(z^2,az^2,a^2z^2)=k[x,y,z]_{(x-1,y,z)}/(z^2)$, where $a=y/x$. This apparently shows that $(1,0,0,0)$ is an embedded point of $X$ (if I get the definition correctly, I couldn't find a real good definition). However, it is still a free $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(P)}=k[x,y]_{(x-1,y)}$-module.

I couldn't show whether $(0,0,0,0)$ is a flat point, but apparently it is also an embedded point.

It will be great if someone can give me a hint on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the definition of an embedded point. For an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and a quasi-coherent sheaf $\widetilde{M}$, an associated point is an associated prime of $M$, or a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ such that $M$ has an element $m$ with $\operatorname{Ann}(m)=\mathfrak{p}$. An *embedded point* is a non-minimal associated prime of the structure sheaf; in this case, it would be a non-minimal associated prime of $k[X]$.

To show that $X$ has no embedded points, find the minimal primes of $k[X]$ (there's a unique minimal prime) and classify annihilators of elements of $k[X]$ (you'll end up with two options, one of which is the unique minimal prime and one which is not a prime ideal).

To show that the obvious map $f:X\to Y$ is not flat, use the same method as (b): since $f$ is finite, the length of the fiber over any two points should be the same by theorem III.9.9. Find two points with fibers of different lengths.

If this isn't quite enough hinting for you, please leave a comment with the progress you make and where you're still stuck.

Comment: In your notation, $k[X]$ means the ring defining $X$, right?

Comment: The coordinate ring of $X$, yes.

Comment: For the flatness part, basically one will have to consider the dimension of $k[X]\otimes k(p)$ as a $k(p)$-vector space, where $k(p)$ is the residue field of $k[Y]$ at $p$. It turns out if one pick $p_1=(x,y)$ and $p_2=(x-1,y)$, one will obtain different dimensions for $k[X]\otimes k(p)$ (3 for the former case, generated by $1,z,w$; 2 for the later case, generated only by $1,w$)

Comment: For the embedded point part, I will have to think about what are the annihilators of the generators $1,w,z$ of $k[X]$ as an $k[Y]$-module. The only useful relation in $k[X]$ should be $xz-yw=0$. I have a hard time finding an annihilating ideal for each of the generator, which is a good hint to towards non-existence of embedded point. But I couldn't classify them explicitly as you suggested.

Comment: Yes, that's correct on the non-flatness. For annihilators, try starting with the fact that any element of $k[X]$ can be written uniquely as $p(x,y)+zq(y)+wr(x,y)$ by applying the relations. (Knowing that there are two options for annihilators of elements should also fairly quickly tell you what they are.)

Comment: Following your suggestion, I was able to show the claim. But what I have was the annihilator has to be zero for any choices of element in $k[X]$. Below is my argument.

Consider $r=p(x,y)+q(y)z+r(x,y)w$ and let $a(x,y)=a_1(y)+xa_2(x,y)\in\operatorname{Ann}(r)$. Then $a(x,y)$ has to satisfy the following equalities:
(1) $a(x,y)p(x,y)=0$, (2): $a_1(y)q(y)=0$ and (3): $ya_2(x,y)q(y)+q(x,y)r(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Using the fact that $k[Y]$ is a UFD, we split the argument in cases of $r$:

In case $p\neq 0$, then (1) implies $a=0$.

In case, $p=0$ but $q\neq 0$, then (2) implies $a_1=0$ and (3) implies $a_2(x,y)(y q(y)+xr(x,y))=0$. $a_2\neq 0$ implies the second factor is nonzero, but this is a contradiction since $y q(y)$ is free of $x$, but $x r(x,y)$ does not.

In case, $p=q=0$ but $r\neq 0$, then (3) implies $ar=0$, so $a=0$.

Hence $a=0$ in all possible cases.

Comment: That's not quite a complete view of the situation - $z$ is annihilated by $z$, for instance. (I don't know why you're only considering elements of the annihilator to lie in the subring $k[x,y]\subset k[X]$.)

Comment: Oh, are we looking for annihilators which is element of $k[X]$? I thought we were only looking for annihilator from $k[Y]$, considering $k[X]$ as a $k[Y]$-module. Then now your comment make sense. Thanks!

Comment: I figured that out already. 

In case $p(x,y)\neq0$, then the set of annihilator is the zero ideal, which is not a prime ideal by the existence of zero divisors.

In case $p(x,y)=0$, then the annihilator is the ideal $(z,w)$. If it is not a minimal prime ideal, then it at least one of $(z)$ or $(w)$ is prime ideal. But they are not. For instance, $xz\in(z)$ but it can also be written as $yw$ in which neither of the factor belongs to $(z)$.